# React Native error - this is a not a function when using the $object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

When calling a function in the React-Redux I'm getting a this is not a function error on my buildLngLat function. Can someone please explain why I am getting this error. It has worked for previously in the past.

```
 const pickUpArr = {
        latitude:  store().home.bookingDetails.pickUp.latitude,
        longitude: store().home.bookingDetails.pickUp.longitude 
    };

    const dropOffArr = {
        latitude:  store().home.bookingDetails.dropOff.latitude,
        longitude: store().home.bookingDetails.dropOff.longitude
    };

    buildLngLat = (position) => {
        return `${position.latitude},${position.longitude}`
    };

    const origin = this.buildLngLat(pickUpArr);
    const destination = this.buildLngLat(dropOffArr);
```

Error output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to go through `this` if you're calling a standalone function. Just call it directly:

```
const buildLngLat = (position) => {
    return `${position.latitude},${position.longitude}`
};

const origin = buildLngLat(pickUpArr);
const destination = buildLngLat(dropOffArr);
```

Comment: Thank so much. I was stuck for a day or so on this problem.